# Send a second E-Mail automatically once the first E-Mail is sent (Excel-VBA-Code)

Tags: excel, email, outlook, vba

I have the following VBA Code to send an E-Mail:

```
Sub First_Email()
    If ExitAll = False Then
        Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
        Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OMail
            .Display
            End With
            signature = OMail.HTMLbody
            With OMail
            .To = "test@test.de"
            .Subject = "First E-Mail"
            .HTMLbody = "<p> Once I click on the send button for this E-Mail I want that the E-Mail in the code below is sent as well.</p>"
            End With
        Set OMail = Nothing
        Set OApp = Nothing
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

This code opens Outlook with the E-Mail described above. Since the user should still have the chance to modify the E-Mail before it is sent the code does not automatically send the E-Mail.

Once the user clicks the **Send Button** the E-Mail is sent. Now, I want to achieve that the E-Mail below is automatically send as well once the user clicks the **Send Button** for the first E-Mail:

```
Sub Second_Email()
    If ExitAll = False Then
        Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
        Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OMail
            .Display
            End With
            signature = OMail.HTMLbody
            With OMail
            .To = "test@test.de"
            .Subject = "Second E-Mail"
            .HTMLbody = "<p> Once I click on the send button for the first E-Mail I want that this E-Mail is sent as well.</p>"
            .send
            End With
        Set OMail = Nothing
        Set OApp = Nothing
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

In contrast to the first E-Mail the user does not have the chance to moidfy the second E-Mail before it is sent. It should immediately be sent once the user clicks the **Send Button** of the first E-Mail.

Do you know how I can achieve to send a second E-Mail automatically once the user clicks the **Send Button** in the first E-Mail?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ItemSend in Outlook. In the ThisOutlookSession module.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Item.To = "test@test.de" Then

        If Item.Subject = "First E-Mail" Then

            Set OMail = CreateItem(0)

            With OMail
                .To = "test@test.de"
                .Subject = "Second E-Mail"
                .HTMLbody = "<p> Once I click on the send button for the first E-Mail I want that this E-Mail is sent as well.</p>"
                .send
            End With

        End If
    end if

End Sub
```

Note: This will run on all mail not just the mail initiated by First_Email in Excel.